# How can I rewind into a node inside of a building in Sorcery! 2?

Tags: sorcery-2

In [Sorcery! 2](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.inkle.sorcery2&hl=en), a new feature (presumably due to the size of the map) is that going inside of buildings or other areas (like sewers) will zoom in to a smaller map of the inside of the location.

Upon exiting the sewers, I decided that I wanted to try a different option for the last choice I made, but found myself unable to zoom back in to the smaller map. I can rewind to the node for entering the sewers in the first place, but can't figure out a way to only go back a node or two within the sewers. Is this possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simply tap on the node through which you entered the building or area. Long pressing on the node, on the other hand, will let you rewind to that node instead.

UPDATE: The latest update to the iOS version changes this - you now use the rewind feature originally developed for Sorcery! 3, sliding back until you reach the point you wish to rewind to. This is presumably coming to the Android version as well.